# How to recognize that ffmpeg pipe ended?

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, process

I am executing an ffmpeg command with a very complex filter and with a pipe within a C# application.  I am putting images into the ffmpeg input stream (pipe)for rendering these images as overlays to the final video.

I want to render images with the pipe until the pipe closes. Unfortunately, I do not know how I can recognize that the pipe of the ffmpeg process has closed. Is there any possibility of recognizing this event within C#?

The process is started like:

```
this._ffmpegProcess = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = this._ffmpegPath,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};

this._ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = ffmpegCmd;
this._ffmpegProcess.OutputDataReceived += this.Proc_DataReceived;
this._ffmpegProcess.ErrorDataReceived += this.Proc_DataReceived;
this._ffmpegProcess.Exited += this._ffmpegProcess_Exited;
this._ffmpegProcess.Start();
this._ffmpegProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
this._ffmpegProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

The rendering happens within a timer:

```
this._renderOverlayTimer = new Timer(this.RenderOverlay);
this._renderOverlayTimer.Change(0, 30);
```

The timer is started right after starting the ffmpeg process:

```
private void RenderOverlay(object state)
{
   using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
   {
      using (var img = GetImage(...))
      {
          img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
          ms.WriteTo(this._ffmpegProcess.StandardInput.BaseStream);
      }
   }
}
```

The problem is that I always receive a "The pipe has ended" error at `ms.WriteTo()`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I now use a named pipe and trace the number of frames to process. The named pipe is closed right after the last frame is processed. This solution leads to a correct video without IOExceptions.

Comment: dear sir, i am also facing same issue, can you help me out? as i am not familiar with named pipe nor how to use that :(

Comment: @Zakir_SZH I posted a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proper way of creating a named pipe and setting as input to a FFmpeg command.

Let's first declare some variables:

```
private Process _process;
private NamedPipeServerStream _pipeServer;
private StreamWriter _pipeStreamWriter;
private const string _pipeName = @"pipe_to_ffmpeg";
private readonly string _pipeStructured = @"\\.\pipe\" + _pipeName;
```

Then let's create a process and pass the necessary parameters:

```
public void Start(string ffmpegPath, int width, int height)
{
    //Example argument, used to export GIFs
    var arguments = "-vsync passthrough " +
        "-f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgra -video_size {width}x{height} " +
        $"-i {_pipeStructured} " +
        "-loop 0 " +
        "-lavfi palettegen=stats_mode=diff[pal],[0:v][pal]paletteuse=new=1:dither=sierra2_4a:diff_mode=rectangle " +
        "-f gif " +
        "-y \"C:\Users\User\Desktop\ffmpeg.gif\"";

    _process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = ffmpegPath,
            Arguments = arguments.Replace("{width}", width.ToString()).Replace("{height}", height.ToString()),
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        }
    };

    _pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(_pipeName, PipeDirection.Out, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
    _pipeStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(_pipeServer);

    var pipeServerThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        //Needs to be in a separate thread or you could use other async methods.
        _pipeServer.WaitForConnection();

        _pipeStreamWriter.AutoFlush = true;
    });
    pipeServerThread.Start();

    _process.Start();
}
```

Then on your render iterator, you can pass data via the `StreamWriter`:

```
public void Encode(byte[] buffer, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
{
    while (!_pipeServer.IsConnected) //TODO: Limit wait period.
        Thread.Sleep(100);

    //Here you may want to spend some time understanding how to properly pass the data to FFmpeg.
    _pipeStreamWriter.BaseStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

Don't forget to clean and dispose everything later:

```
public void Finish()
{
    _pipeServer.WaitForPipeDrain();
    _pipeStreamWriter.Dispose();
    _pipeServer.Dispose();

    _process.WaitForExit();
}
```